# Error while installing iconv on windows by ruby2.0.0

Tags: ruby, installation, iconv

Error while installing iconv on windows by ruby2.0.0 
Error while installing iconv on windows by ruby2.0.0 
I'm trying to install the iconv , but when I run the following command:

```
gem install iconv
```

my result:

```
Temporarily enhancing Path to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Error : Error installing iconv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150217-3212-i8hzmh.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby/Ruby200/bin/ruby
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/
    --enable-config-charset
    --disable-config-charset
    --with-config-charset
    --without-config-charset
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

please help me!!!!
THX.

Comment: you can try have a look at https://github.com/francois/piston/issues/11

Comment: I'd rather ` Check the mkmf.log file for more details.`

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem this evening (Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.3). The solution in my case was as follows:

1. Install the "Complete package, except sources" from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
2. Run `gem install iconv -v '1.0.4' -- --with-iconv-dir=/path/to/GnuWin32`

If that doesn't work, I also followed the instructions here first: http://donpepeto.com/2014/09/20/fixing-c-libraries-on-your-rubyrails-install-on-windows/ (Copying the contents of /bin, /include and /lib from the GnuWin32 install) They didn't work on their own, but once I'd run the setup, I was able to install the gem, so maybe that helped. I also got an error about a missing .gitignore, but I ignored that, ran gem install... again and it worked.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure iconv's DLLs (found in the installation bin folder) are located in your PATH. If they're not, iconv.so won't load (LoadError). Run a DLL dependency tool on iconv.so if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue on windows 10. Thanks @Emma Burrows and @ZeWaren. Following worked for me,

1. Install libiconv; http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
2. Copy files from `/include` and `/lib` into `/bin` folder, for me `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`
3. Set PATH (Environment Variable) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`
4. Exceute (Tricky one): `gem install iconv -- --with-iconv-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\"` and during gem install quickly past files from `/bin` into `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\iconv-1.0.4\ext\iconv`

[image]