# How to resolve "cannot load such file -- iconv" in Rhodes framework

Tags: ruby, rhodes

I would like to create a new app using the Rhodes framework but I have some errors like this:

```
C:\Users\TOUCH>rhodes app pharma
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/res/generators/rhogen.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/bin/rhogen:5    :in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/bin/rhodes:4    :in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12/bin/rhodes:4    :in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhodes:22:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhodes:22:in `<main>'
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: thanks, but when i try to install gem iconv i have some errors:ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4/ext/ic
onv
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160323-5976-im333h.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: how to install iconv  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558578/error-while-installing-iconv-on-windows-by-ruby2-0-0