# Iconv gem refuses to install on ruby 2.2 (windows)

Tags: ruby, windows, iconv

While installing iconv on windows I get the following errors

following the advice of a users post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558578/error-while-installing-iconv-on-windows-by-ruby2-0-0) I tried the following after installing libconv http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

```
gem install iconv -v '1.0.4' -- --with-iconv-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32
```

I had no success, below are the output errors.

**error in cmd**

```
C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\macros\experiments\core_scripts\app>gem install iconv -v '1.0.4' -- --with-iconv-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-iconv-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160919-12804-5eyr6.rb extconf.rb --with-iconv-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --enable-config-charset
    --disable-config-charset
    --with-config-charset
    --without-config-charset
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/iconv-1.0.4/gem_make.out

C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\macros\experiments\core_scripts\app>
```

**gem_make.out**

```
C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160919-12804-5eyr6.rb extconf.rb --with-iconv-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-iconv-dir
--with-iconv-include
--without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
--with-iconv-lib
--without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
--enable-config-charset
--disable-config-charset
--with-config-charset
--without-config-charset
--with-iconvlib
--without-iconvlib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried putting double quotes around the dir name (there are spaces after all)?

Comment: gave it a shot, still errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by,
[Error while installing iconv on windows by ruby2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558578/error-while-installing-iconv-on-windows-by-ruby2-0-0/40397017#40397017)

Tricky part was copying files from /include, /bin and /lib of /GnuWin32 quickly `into /Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4/ext/iconv` when gem install goes to `Building native extensions.  This could take a while...`

Hope this will help someone.